# "fread(serial)" and "fscanf(serial)" from Matlab to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, serial-port, fread, scanf

everyone,

now i'm writing a C# programm according to a piece of matlab code.

In matlab code there are two commands to read data from the COM-Port:

```
A=fscanf(com_Port1,'%s');
A=fread(com_Port1,1008); //two sentences are next to each other like i write here.
```

For the first command "A=fscanf(com_Port1,'%s');" i used:

```
string A = com_Port1.ReadExisting();
```

and it seems all right, because no error warning;

for the second command "A=fread(com_Port1,1008);" i used:

```
double[] B = new double[1008];
for (int i = 0; i <= 1008 - 1; i++)
                {
                    B[i] = com_Port1.ReadByte() ;
                }
```

then it shows an error:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred
>   in System.dll".

So i'm assuming that "ReadExisting" has read all the data, and "ReadByte" can't read available data any more, is that right?Could someone tell me where i war wrong? thank you.

Yours

Adam

Add at Nov.20.2013, below is the code i have wrote, i have tried "Read()","ReadTo()","ReadLine()", but i still get the error at "otdr_Portobject.ReadByte()", i have no idea any more.

```
 otdr_Portobject = new otdr_Port(cB_portNames.SelectedItem.ToString());

            otdr_Portobject.Open();
            btn_Stop.Enabled = true;
            btn_Start.Enabled = false;
            /*if (!otdr_Portobject.IsOpen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not open");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial Port opened");
            };*/

            //string start = "start";
            otdr_Portobject.Write("start");
            char[] b9 = new char[7];
            otdr_Portobject.Read(b9, 0, 7);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            //string isready = "isready";
            otdr_Portobject.Write("isready");
            char[] b10 = new char[10];
            otdr_Portobject.Read(b10, 0, 10);
            //A = otdr_Portobject.ReadTo("\n");

            //string rdatb = "rdatb";
            int int32_Auslesekommando = Convert.ToInt32(pointsCon.Value-1);
            otdr_Portobject.Write("rdatb " + int32_Auslesekommando.ToString("X4") + "\n");
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            char[] b11 = new char[18];
            otdr_Portobject.Read(b11, 0, 18);
            //A = otdr_Portobject.ReadTo("\n");
            //A = otdr_Portobject.ReadTo("\n");
            //int A1=otdr_Portobject.ReadByte();

            //brechnen Y Axis
            int pointNum = Convert.ToInt32(pointsCon.Value);
            double[] B = new double[pointNum];

             //int byteNum=otdr_Portobject.BytesToRead;
            //if ( byteNum== 0) return;

           try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= pointNum - 1; i++)
                {
                    B[i] =System.Convert.ToDouble( otdr_Portobject.ReadByte() )* 256;
                }
            }
             catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the c#-docs:

*ReadExsting: Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object..*

MATLAB:

`%s` format for `fscanf`: *Read series of characters, until find white space.*

So you should probably switch to `ReadTo`, specifying a white-space character to stop.

Or call `Read` yourself until the returned value is a whitespace-character.

Comment: i have tried "ReadTo("\n");" and "ReadLine();" but there was always the error" A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in System.dll", it seems to be the Port's problem, but i used code 'if (!otdr_Portobject.IsOpen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not open");
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Serial Port opened");' and it showed "Serial port opened"

Comment: You replaced `ReadExisting` with `ReadTo` / `ReadLine`, correct?

Comment: yes, ReadTo("\n"); or RindLine(); but it still shows the error at com_Port1.ReadByte();

Comment: Then you should maybe call `Read` yourself as long as no whitespace character appears. The whitespace were MATLAB stops might be normal space character or a tab etc. ReadTo('\n') would then probably read to the end as well...

Comment: i have also tried "Read();" see above in Question, but i still can't get rid of the erroe. :(